# Почему блокируется com порт при чтении из под php

Tags: php, linux, bash, serial

Необходимо работать напрямую с com портом (купюроприемник cashcode), ubuntu 16.04 & php7.1

При включении пк, при первом обращении к com порту происходит подвисание ком порта при попытке считать ответ. Временно лечу запуском сторонней программы (которая нормально с ком портами работает), после нее все работает как надо.
Смотрел исходники одной из такой программ, ничего сверх естественного там не происходит, никаких изменений в конфигурацию порта или чего подобного не вносится.

[либа для работы с ком портом](https://github.com/slowdream/client/blob/master/app/libs/cashcode/CashValidator.php)

[Хелпер для купюроприемника](https://github.com/slowdream/client/blob/master/app/Helpers/CashCode.php)

[Сам контроллер](https://github.com/slowdream/client/blob/master/app/Jobs/CashCode.php)

Comment: modemmanager уже снесли?

Comment: скорость на порту выставить надо

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, modemmanager то тут причем ?)

Comment: @eri, да, конечно. Все настройки прописаны и сверены побуквенно с теми, что указаны в исходниках рабочей программы.

Comment: modemmanager может блокировать интерфейсные файлы последовательных устройств. логика работы у него такая. причём, что самое плохое — спорадически. если работаете с последовательным устройством самостоятельно, я бы рекомендовал для начала удалить этот пакет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не помогло.

Comment: А у вас только один процесс использует com-порт или несколько?

Comment: @ilyaplot, только один. Причем проблема именно с php и именно при первом запуске пк. Если в начале запустить любую другую прогу работающую с этим купюроприемником, то все ок. Читал исходники одной из них, ничего криминального не обнаружил.
http://collabedit.com/cmsa9

Comment: Ещё раз! Я в исходниках вижу только `fopen` - Скорость выставлять кто будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В исходниках видно что для доступа к порту используется функция `fopen` - это обычное чтение из файла. Она не устанавливает параметры подключения на порту. Также не вижу в коде никакой другой функции для инициализации порта.

Когда стартуете стороннюю программку - она в первую очередь устанавливает скорость и стоп-биты, контроль потока.

Для корректной работы рекомендую настроить порт до запуска php или средствами php до открытия порта.

Как изменить параметры последовательного порта в Linux (c opennet)

Вывод на экран текущих параметров:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a
setserial -g /dev/ttyS0
```

Включение Hardware flow control (RTS/CTS):

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 crtscts
```

Установка скорости порта:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

Установка прерывания и типа UART:

```
setserial /dev/ttyS0 auto_irq skip_test autoconfig
setserial /dev/ttyS0 irq 5 uart 16550A  skip_test
```

Comment: видимо моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я считал отсутствие флага как "выкл", а присутствие, как "вкл" режима, когда по факту тут играет роль знак "-" (crtscts и -crtscts к примеру). Я прав ?

Сравнил через сервис вывод конфига порта рабочего и нет, получилось 
`stty -F /dev/ttyS0 min 0 -hupcl -icrnl -ixon -isig -icanon -iexten -echo ignbrk noflsh -opost`
все заработало.

Comment: присутствие значит изменение, отсутствие - оставить как есть